# Android bitmap decode stream returns null

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I've made the following code to get a `bitmap` size.

```
// Decode the Uri to get the bitmap
BitmapFactory.Options optionsSize = new BitmapFactory.Options();
optionsSize.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap originalBimap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, optionsSize);

// Get original size
int width = optionsSize.outWidth;
int height = optionsSize.outHeight;
```

What is strange, is the varaibles `height` and `width` have the correct values but `originalBimap` is `null`.

The `Uri` targets a picture in gallery (`content://media/...`).

Did I make something wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. When you set `inJustDecodeBounds` to true, then it does not return the bitmap. It only queries to set the "out" fields of `BitmapFactory.Options`.

[inJustDecodeBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)